# Error on get data API call using Angular

Tags: javascript, angularjs, web-services, http, xmlhttprequest

> I am trying to get medicine name from TrueMD using api. I am using this from my localhost. For that reason web service security I also include 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' as a null still same error of security. Is there somthing that I am missing?

```
    $scope.medicines = [];
    var search = "crocin";
    var api_key = "API_KEY";

    $http.get("http://www.truemd.in/api/medicine_suggestions?id=" + search + "?key=" + api_key)
    .then(function(response){ 
        response.header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin', "null");
        $scope.medicines = response.data; 
        console.log($scope.medicine);
    });
```

Comment: The error is **XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://www.truemd.in/api/medicine_suggestions?id=crocin?key=api_key. Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:8080' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 401.**

Answer (score 1):

Because your GET request is invalid. When using several arguments, the separator to use is '&'.

Your request should be:
"**http://truemd.in/api/medicine_suggestions?id=crocin&key=XXXX**"

Therefore, your code should looks like

```
$http.get("http://www.truemd.in/api/medicine_suggestions?id=" + search + "&key=" + api_key)
.then(function(response){
    ...
}
```

PS: The "Access-Control-Allow-Origin" is a server-side header. Setting it in the request won't do anything. You can get rid of it.

PS 2: You're trying to change the headers of the server response. This has no sense. I think you misunderstand the way it works :(